# File upload: "File exceeded max_file_size"

Tags: php, html, file-upload

My HTML form is like

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000" />
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="50" />
```

However, when I upload a file of 3mb, it gives error that:

> Problem: File exceeded max_file_size"

Comment: Webhosts usually set the max file size to 2MB. There are a couple of ways around this using `.htaccess` rules and `init_set()`, but I'll leave the explanation to the answerers.

Answer (score 4):

Last I checked, `MAX_FILE_SIZE` was in bytes. 3MB is equal to either 3,000,000 or 3,145,728 (depending on unit convention), both of which are significantly higher than the 20,000 you specified.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to increase the value of the max file size.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="67108864" />
```

You will also need to update the php.ini file with the following values to allow up to 64MB files:

```
memory_limit = 96M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Comment: That won't help if the limit is set in php.ini. If this would work, ANYONE could override a server's file size limit simply by fiddling with a form field.

Comment: Ok, Updated answer as advised. :)

Answer (score 1):

edit the php.ini
help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: if you can't edit. add a new file named php.ini in the root of your web hosting with the changes you want. same is the case woth .htaccess